# Why is my NSFetchRequest not updating my array as I expect? And does `shouldRefreshRefetchedObjects` make any difference?

Tags: core-data, swiftui, updates, nsfetchrequest

I do not understand why this code does not work to update a list when navigating "back" from a `DetailView()`. As far as I can tell, I'm calling a new `fetchRequest` each time I want to update the list and it seems that request should always return object with current properties. But as others have said they are "stale", reflecting whatever was the property BEFORE the update was committed in the DetailView. And tapping a Navigation link from a "Stale" row, opens a DetailView with the current values of the properties, so I know they have been sacved to the context (haven't they?).

First I have a "dataservice" like this:

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

protocol CategoryDataServiceProtocol {
    func getCategories() -> [Category]
    func getCategoryById(id: NSManagedObjectID) -> Category?
    func addCategory(name: String, color: String)
    func updateCategory(_ category: Category)
    func deleteCategory(_ category: Category)
}

class CategoryDataService: CategoryDataServiceProtocol {

    var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext = PersistenceController.shared.viewContext


    ///Shouldn't this next function always return an updated version of my list of categories?
    func getCategories() -> [Category] {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Category> = Category.fetchRequest()
        let sort: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Category.name_, ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

///This line appears to do nothing if I insert it: 
        request.shouldRefreshRefetchedObjects = true

        do {
            ///A print statement here does run, so it's getting this far...
            print("Inside get categories func")
            return try viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }

    func getCategoryById(id: NSManagedObjectID) -> Category? {
        do {
            return try viewContext.existingObject(with: id) as? Category
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func addCategory(name: String, color: String) {
        let newCategory = Category(context: viewContext)
        newCategory.name = name
        newCategory.color = color
        saveContext()
    }

    func updateCategory(_ category: Category) {
        saveContext()
    }

    func deleteCategory(_ category: Category) {
        viewContext.delete(category)
        saveContext()
    }

    func saveContext() {
        PersistenceController.shared.save()
    }
}

class MockCategoryDataService: CategoryDataService {

    override init() {
        super .init()
        self.viewContext = PersistenceController.preview.viewContext
        print("MOCK INIT")

        func addCategory(name: String, color: String) {
            let newCategory = Category(context: viewContext)
            newCategory.name = name
            newCategory.color = color
            saveContext()
        }

    }

}
```

And I have a viewModel like this:

```
import SwiftUI

extension CategoriesList {

    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

        let dataService: CategoryDataServiceProtocol

        @Published var categories: [Category] = []

        init(dataService: CategoryDataServiceProtocol = CategoryDataService()) {
            self.dataService = dataService
        }

        func getCategories() {
            self.categories = dataService.getCategories()
        }

        func deleteCategories(at offsets: IndexSet) {
            offsets.forEach { index in
                let category = categories[index]
                dataService.deleteCategory(category)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then my view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CategoriesList: View {

    @StateObject private var viewModel: CategoriesList.ViewModel

    init(viewModel: CategoriesList.ViewModel = .init()) {
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
    }

    @State private var isShowingSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.categories) { category in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: CategoryDetail(category: category)) {
                    CategoryRow(category: category)
                        .padding(0)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: { index in
                    viewModel.deleteCategories(at: index)
                    viewModel.getCategories()
                })
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .onAppear(perform: {
                viewModel.getCategories()
            })
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Categories"))
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading, content: { EditButton() })
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(
                        action: {
                            isShowingSheet = true
                            viewModel.getCategories()
                        },
                        label: { Image(systemName: "plus.circle").font(.system(size: 20)) }
                    )
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet, onDismiss: {
                viewModel.getCategories()
            }, content: {
                CategoryForm()
            })
        }
    }
}

struct CategoriesList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let viewModel: CategoriesList.ViewModel = .init(dataService: MockCategoryDataService())
        return CategoriesList(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}
```

So, when I navigate to the DetailView and change the name of the category, all is fine there. But then tapping the back button or swiping to return to the view - and the view still shows the old name.

I understand that the @Published array of [Category] is probably not looking at changes to objects inside the array, only if an object is removed or added, I guess.

But why is my list not updating anyways, since I am calling viewModel.getCategories() and that is triggering the fetch request in the dataservice getCategories function?

And if Combine is the answer, then how? Or what else am I missing? Does `request.shouldRefreshRefetchedObjects = true` offer anything? Or is it a bug as I read here: https://mjtsai.com/blog/2019/10/17/core-data-derived-attributes/

Comment: CoreData objects are ObservableObjects if you want to see changes you have to use the ObservedObject wrapper

Comment: Thank you! I updated my `CategoryRow` which is used in the CategoriesList view to include `struct CategoryRow: View {    @ObservedObject var category: Category ...` and that seems to work so far. Thank you very much!